# Only few files are visible from 5TB exFat external hdd on Galaxy S8+

Tags: file-system, usb-on-the-go

I have a 5TB external storage with many RAW photos and videos. They are sorted by dates in folders and the hdd itself is almost full.
When I connect it to my PC, it recognizes all files and directories.
However, when I run it on my Android phone, only few folders and files are visible. Most directories appear empty or doesn't even show up.

Does Android have issue recognizing larger HDD drives? It is a seagate 2.5 inch drive with 5TB storage formatted in exFat format.